# A cog wheel math puzzle

Tags: combinatorics

A machine has 4 cog wheels in connection. The largest wheel has 242 teeth and the others have 66,48 and 26 respectively. How many rotations must the largest wheel make before each of the wheel is back in its starting position?

My progress so far:
$$\mathrm{lcm}(242,66,48,26) = 40656$$
Then 
$$\mathrm{number\,of\,turns\,of\,largest\,wheel}=\frac{40656}{242} = 168$$

But the answer provided is $312$... Can anyone explain?

Comment: When you corrected the apparent typo that Christian Blatter pointed out, changing $28$ to $26$, you needed to recompute the lcm, which is now $75504$, not $40656$.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation is correct, but there is a typo in the problem: Replace $28$ by $26$, and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

(teeth on cog #1)×(turns of cog #1)÷(teeth on smaller cog)=(turns of smaller cog)

For each small cog:
242×168÷66
=616=2×2×2×7×11

242×168÷48
=847=7×11×11

242×168÷28
=1,452=2×2×3×11×11.

No common factors exist for the three results.

Your answer is the solution.